# The recommended window size sent with the WM_DPICHANGED message is too big

Tags: c++, winapi, dpi

My application supports per-monitor DPI-awareness version 2. I have two monitors - one scaled at 100% and the other at 125%. When moving my application's window to the monitor with DPI scaling and setting the new size using the recommended size given in the `WM_DPICHANGED` message, the resulting client area size is a few pixels bigger than it should be.

For example, the window's client area size in my case is 300x200 pixels. On the monitor with 125% scaling, the scaling factor is 1.25, so the resulting client area size should be 375x250. When I set the window size using the recommended one received in the `WM_DPICHANGED` message, the resulting client area size is 377x252. Windows [documentation claims](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt807679(v=vs.85).aspx) scaling to be linear, yet it fails to work like that.

Minimal example:

```
#include <Windows.h>

void set_window_size(HWND window, DWORD window_style, int width, int height)
{
    UINT dpi = GetDpiForWindow(window);
    float scaling_factor = static_cast<float>(dpi) / USER_DEFAULT_SCREEN_DPI;

    RECT scaled_size;
    scaled_size.left = 0;
    scaled_size.top = 0;
    scaled_size.right = static_cast<LONG>(width * scaling_factor);
    scaled_size.bottom = static_cast<LONG>(height * scaling_factor);

    // Adjust the size to account for non-client area
    AdjustWindowRectExForDpi(&scaled_size, window_style, false, 0, dpi);

    SetWindowPos(window, nullptr, 0, 0, scaled_size.right - scaled_size.left, scaled_size.bottom - scaled_size.top, SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOACTIVATE | SWP_NOMOVE));
}

// These sizes are for the client area
constexpr auto window_width = 300;
constexpr auto window_height = 200;

constexpr auto window_class_name = L"startup_dialog";
constexpr auto window_style = WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW;

LRESULT CALLBACK window_procedure(HWND window, UINT message, WPARAM w_param, LPARAM l_param)
{
    switch (message)
    {
        case WM_DESTROY:
        {
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            return 0;
        }

        case WM_DPICHANGED:
        {
            RECT* rect = reinterpret_cast<RECT*>(l_param);
            SetWindowPos(window, nullptr, rect->left, rect->top, rect->right - rect->left, rect->bottom - rect->top, SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOACTIVATE);
        }
    }

    return DefWindowProcW(window, message, w_param, l_param);
}

int CALLBACK wWinMain(HINSTANCE instance, HINSTANCE prev_instance, PWSTR cmd_line, int cmd_show)
{
    SetProcessDpiAwarenessContext(DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT_PER_MONITOR_AWARE_V2);

    WNDCLASSEXW window_class;
    window_class.cbSize = sizeof(window_class);
    window_class.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    window_class.lpfnWndProc = window_procedure;
    window_class.cbClsExtra = 0;
    window_class.cbWndExtra = 0;
    window_class.hInstance = instance;
    window_class.hIcon = nullptr;
    window_class.hCursor = nullptr;
    window_class.hbrBackground = reinterpret_cast<HBRUSH>(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
    window_class.lpszMenuName = nullptr;
    window_class.lpszClassName = window_class_name;
    window_class.hIconSm = nullptr;

    RegisterClassExW(&window_class));
    HWND window = CreateWindowExW(0, window_class_name, L"Example", window_style, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, 0, nullptr, nullptr, instance, nullptr);

    // Set the initial DPI-scaled window size
    set_window_size(window, window_style, window_width, window_height);

    ShowWindow(window, SW_SHOWNORMAL);

    // Message loop
    MSG message;
    int result;

    while ((result = GetMessageW(&message, nullptr, 0, 0)) != 0)
    {
        if (result == -1)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            TranslateMessage(&message);
            DispatchMessageW(&message);
        }
    }

    return static_cast<int>(message.wParam);
}
```

Error checking is removed for brevity.
The example requires Windows 10 SDK 14393+ to compile and Windows 10 1607+ to run.

How do I fix the incorrect recommended window size given in the `WM_DPICHANGED` message?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem occurs due to a Windows bug, which causes the new window size to be incorrectly calculated. The bug can be worked around by handling the [`WM_GETDPISCALEDSIZE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt807679(v=vs.85).aspx) message and calculating the new window size yourself.

Example of handling the message based on the question's example:

```
case WM_GETDPISCALEDSIZE:
{
    UINT dpi = static_cast<UINT>(w_param);
    float scaling_factor = static_cast<float>(dpi) / USER_DEFAULT_SCREEN_DPI;

    RECT client_area;
    client_area.right *= scaling_factor;
    client_area.bottom *= scaling_factor;

    RECT window_rectangle;
    window_rectangle.left = 0;
    window_rectangle.top = 0;
    window_rectangle.right = static_cast<LONG>(window_width * scaling_factor);
    window_rectangle.bottom = static_cast<LONG>(window_height * scaling_factor);

    if (!AdjustWindowRectExForDpi(&window_rectangle, window_style, false, 0, dpi))
    {
        // Error handling
        return 0;
    }

    SIZE* new_size = reinterpret_cast<SIZE*>(l_param);
    new_size->cx = window_rectangle.right - window_rectangle.left;
    new_size->cy = window_rectangle.bottom - window_rectangle.top;

    return 1;
}
```

Note that with this approach you must make the `window_width` and `window_height` variables available in the message. In the question's example this was done using constexpr global variables.

Alternative approach, which scales based on the previous client area size, but is likely slightly slower:

```
case WM_GETDPISCALEDSIZE:
{
    UINT dpi = static_cast<UINT>(w_param);
    float scaling_factor = static_cast<float>(dpi) / USER_DEFAULT_SCREEN_DPI;

    RECT client_area;

    if (!GetClientRect(window, &client_area))
    {
        // Error handling
        return 0;
    }

    client_area.right = static_cast<LONG>(client_area.right * scaling_factor);
    client_area.bottom = static_cast<LONG>(client_area.bottom * scaling_factor);

    if (!AdjustWindowRectExForDpi(&client_area, window_style, false, 0, dpi))
    {
        // Error handling
        return 0;
    }

    SIZE* new_size = reinterpret_cast<SIZE*>(l_param);
    new_size->cx = client_area.right - client_area.left;
    new_size->cy = client_area.bottom - client_area.top;

    return 1;
}
```

Also worth noting that there seems to be another bug, where if you breakpoint in either of the above-shown messages, the recommended rectangle passed to [`WM_DPICHANGED`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn312083(v=vs.85).aspx) will be incorrect.

Comment: Why the strange `reinterpret_cast` for `w_param` instead of simply `UINT dpi = static_cast<UINT>(w_param)`?

Comment: @zett42 Because `w_param` is `UINT_PTR`, which in turn is an unsigned 64-bit value pointer, which can't be `static_cast` to `UINT`.

Comment: Doubt it's a bug. The design just differs from your expectation.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Windows [documentation claims](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt807679(v=vs.85).aspx) (see return value section) linear scaling, yet it fails to scale linearly, even for the total window area itself. I've found no mathmetical calculations tha would result in such a size. Feel free to test yourself. The fix in this answer makes the scaling work like it's described in the documentation.

Comment: `UINT_PTR` is **not** a pointer despite its misleading name. It's just an integral type that is *large enough* to hold a pointer. On Win64 it's typedef'd as `unsigned __int64`, otherwise it's `unsigned int`. So `static_cast` will indeed work. [MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: @zett42 You're right. In this case the problem was that I cast it to a reference. I've corrected the answer. Thank you.

Comment: 300x200 goes to 375x250 for me in the scenario you describe. I think that the system works as designed, and the "bug" you have found does not exist

Comment: @DavidHeffernan What Windows version are you using? I'm on Windows 10 Professional N 1703 15063.483 (using winver). Main monitor is 2560x1440 @ 100%, second one is 1920x1200 @ 125%. The problem very much does manifest for me on this setup. I'd presume it's more likely the bug occurs due to a specific hardware configuration - mine's not very common.

Comment: Likely you misdiagnose. After all, you talk about client size. It's the window size that is scaled.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan As described in my original comment to you, even the scaled window size is not correct for a 1.25 scaling factor. With the fix disabled, the window size originally is 302x232, but when moved to the monitor with 125% scaling, the resulting window size is 379x291. With a 1.25 scaling factor it should be 378x290 (rounded up). Documentation describes linear scaling, but yet the results are non-linear for me. The resulting expected size difference at higher scaling levels is even worse.

Comment: You seem to be mistaken believing that client size is scaled. Window size scales fine.

Comment: You seem to be misunderstanding. Please do re-read my previous comments. Even the window size doesn't scale fine for me. If the window size would be scaled correctly, then the client size would also be correct -
 the error's same for both. Neither scales correctly according to my calculations, no matter how I try. I use ShareX's capture region function to see the sizes of different windows. But since we've already established that scaling works correctly for you, I would be very interested in your setup, as I stated previously.

Comment: I'm sure you are misdiagnosing this. Window size scales as expected. No reason to expect client size to scale the same way. Anyway, you've made your mind up. That's fine.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I've already told you three times that the window size **doesn't scale properly either** on **my setup**. It might on yours, but it sure doesn't on mine. I'd like to also note, that if the window size itself scaled properly, then the client area would be of the correct size. But in this case the window size fails to scale properly, thus also causing the client area size to be incorrect. I would be glad to change my mind, but you've so far refused to provide further information and simply state that I'm doing it wrong, although I've contradicted all the points you've brought up.

Comment: That logic is flawed. Perfectly possible for the non client area to scale differently and so client area has to make up the difference. Anyway, there's not much more to be said. I don't believe what you state. No problem. You've submitted a bug report I presume?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Documentation states it scales linearly - neither the window size or client area size do. But, OK. I've not reported the bug, as I do not have a support license - I'm a hobbyist. From others' experieneces, it seems that [reporting bugs to Microsoft is practically impossible](http://www.schveiguy.com/blog/2017/05/how-to-report-a-bug-to-microsoft/), if you don't have expensive support plans. Neither do I know any insiders, so I just have to use a workaround for the problem.

Comment: Client size does not, window size does. You are misdiagnosing. In my test app, for instance, client size 600x400 at 100% scales to 752x502 at 125%. But the window size scales as expected. What do you think is more likely? MS get it right, or you get it right?

Comment: I've already stated four times that the window size doesn't scale as expected either. The 300x200 client size test app from the question has a window size of 302x232 at 100% and a window size of 379x291 at 125%. Scaling factor for 125% is 1.25. Thus the window x-axis size should be 302*1.25≈378, y-axis size should be 232*1.25=290. 379≠378, 291≠290. As stated before, I'd be interested in knowing the details of your setup and seeing the code of your test app (if it differs from the example in the question) Also, it doesn't matter who is more likely to get it right, but rather who gets it right.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Could at least give me the details of your Windows version to help me narrow on what setups the bug might occur?

Comment: 302x232 goes to 378x290 here, I'm sure you have misdiagnosed. Anyway I am done. No windows bug.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan "Doesn't occur on my setup" for such a bug is hardly a good solution. As I stated before, I believe it might be affected by my setup (a dual-monitor setup with a 2560x1440 and 1920x1200 monitors is probably a very rare occurrence). I understand you're done with this, but as I've begged before, please at least give me your OS version details to help narrow down the problem in future. You can view them easily by typing "winver" into the start menu.

Comment: I just don't believe you. But it doesn't matter to me. Never mind.

Comment: I find such an attitude for solving problems incredibly depressing and surprising. Next time if you're going to bother, at least be willing to state some incredibly basic details of your setup that are relevant to the problem.

Comment: With Windows version 19613 (currently Fast Ring, probably late 2020 release), this bug still occurs to me while developing a new Win32 application. @DavidHeffernan your comments were not helpful. Additions to the code posted here: It only works when the application is started on a screen with USER_DEFAULT_SCREEN_DPI (e. g. 96), to work correctly, the value must be adjusted to the initial screen's DPI (using e. g. GetDpiForWindow()), and in subsequent calls must be replaced by the previous' monitors DPI.

Comment: It's 2023, this bug still occurs for me, and non-default DPI is still a PITA on Windows 11...